# JS-Cookie - Can't set a Cookie from a helper function

Tags: javascript, reactjs

I have a Login form where if the user is successful, we will set an authToken in the Cookie.

```
enter code here
```

```js
if (res.status === 202) {
                    const result = await res.json();
                    console.log(
                        "This is auth token before setting" + result.token
                    );
                    //setCookie(result.token);
                    Cookies.set("authToken", result.token, {
                        secure: true,
                        sameSite: "strict",
                        expires: 1,
                        domain: "localhost:3001",
                    });

                    localStorage.setItem("username", username);
                    console.log(
                        "This is Cookie auth token " + Cookies.get("authToken")
                    );
                    history.push("/home");
                }
```

Now, I will use this code elsewhere so I wanted to create a helper function.

This doesn't work and I'm not sure why.

```js
const setCookie = (token) => {
    //console.log("this is from setCookie " + token);
    console.log(
        Cookies.set("authToken", token, {
            secure: true,
            sameSite: "strict",
            expires: 1,
            domain: "localhost:3001",
        })
    );
};
export default setCookie;
```

However, this seems to work just fine

```js
import Cookies from "js-cookie";

const setCookie = (token) => {
    //console.log("this is from setCookie " + token);
    console.log(
        Cookies.set("authToken", token);
};
export default setCookie;
```

I'm not sure why this is the case. Can anyone suggest why how I can fix this please?

Comment: Why are you wrapping your `Cookies.set` inside of a a `console.log`?  Seems like that might be causing issues.

Comment: My bad, that was just me printing out what was happening. It works just fine if I remove the console.log :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

After making some changes, this seems to work.

```js
Cookies.set("authToken", result.token, {
                        //  secure: true,
                        sameSite: "strict",
                        expires: 1,
                        //  domain: "localhost",
                    });
```

As soon as I make the cookie secure it stops working.